# Bootstrapper design pattern using Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework with IoC-container

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, caliburn.micro

The WPF application uses Caliburn.Micro as MVVM framework. CM has it's built in IoC-Container named **SimpleContainer**, I replaced it with **Castle.Windsor** container. *(But container type does not matter here I guess.)* CM uses a `Bootstrapper.Configure()` method where container can be configured. After that `Bootstrapper.OnStartup()` method starts application displaying a View for root ViewModel. So container configures before first View appears. In my case container configuration a pretty complex and may cause errors. For example I want to deserialize some XML files from app directory to objects and register them as components in container. So I want to get a SplashScreen to see container configuring progress, and then if all OK, splash disappears, container resolves root item and application starts as expected. If not - problem shown on splashscreen. I can't get in mind how to get a `SplashScreenView` (binded to `SplashScreenViewModel`) before I get a configured container. So application divides on "before" and "after" container. How can that issue can be solved? Is there any patterns? Is it OK to partly configure container in `Configure` and partly somewhere else, after it Resolved some components? Or maybe there is a practic to use container instance "inside" components  resolved by another container instance? Thanks.

```
public class CastleModernUIBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private WindsorContainer _container;
        public CastleModernUIBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();
            // here components are registered. 
            // I want perform complex container configuration here,
            // but I can't vizualize what happens here.
            _container.Register(Component.For<LoadingSplashScreenViewModel>());
            // ...
        }
        // ...
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // after we resolving first element from container
            DisplayRootViewFor<LoadingSplashScreenViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has a built-in (as in I don't know how it works) Splash Screen. Just use "Add new item" on your project. It does work with Caliburn.

It's only a simple bitmap, but it takes care of the appearance. You can handle your errors as normal data.

You don't want your Splash window to be the Root View anyway.